# How to dynamically create queries in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

So I am trying to implement a single INSERT(and other CRUD operations) method for different entities:

```
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

    @Column(name = "ID", isPrimaryKey = true)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "MONEY")
    private double money;

    //setters and getter
}
```

In my Service I have:

```
    public void add(Client c){
        clients.add(c);
        persistent.add(c.getClass());
    }
```

This method `add(Client c)` will call `persistent.add(c.getClass())`. This method looks like:

```
    public void add(Class<?> classOfObjectToBeAdded){
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        queryCreator = new AddQueryCreator(classOfObjectToBeAdded);
        String finalQuery = queryCreator.getQuery();
        System.out.println(finalQuery);
        //add to database with prepared statement
    }
```

Now, because this add method is an INSERT query, I need to dynamically create the INSERT based on the object I give. I have that `AddQueryCreator` that will create my `INSERT`. And this is my problem, how do I do this? An example would be: `INSERT INTO mydb.CLIENT VALUES(NULL,"John",5000)`.
I managed to scan the class for the class annotations to get the table's name and I managed to scan the fields and take the annotations + get those values from the annotation:

```
(...)
public @interface Column {
    String name();
    boolean isPrimaryKey() default false;
}

(...)
public @interface Table {
    String name();
}
```

For having another entity, ex: `Fireman`, my `INSERT` would look like `INSERT INTO mydb.FIREMAN VALUES(NULL,"Nick",25,5,...)` where 25 is the age and 5 is the department. I put NULL, because that field is the PK and has AUTO INCREMENT.
How do I create that INSERT (and the other CRUD operations) dynamically?
I do not want to use existing ORMs because I am trying to learn stuff.

Comment: You have two main options: 1) You code the SQL and JDBC manually for each INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, and SELECT, or 2) You use an ORM. It seems you are trying option #2, but you decided to write your own ORM instead of using an existing one... for learning purposes.

Comment: I really wish I can do this. This will apply my knowledge from different chapters and I want some advice.

Comment: Writing an ORM is not a minor task (believe me, I've done it, it has taken me 5 years so far, and many to come I guess...). The basic CRUD operations should be easy, safe for the PK autogeneration that could be tricky. You'll need to retrieve the database metadata (tables, views, columns, data types, converters, PKs, FKs, constraints, etc.), and that's not standardized (even if JDBC says so). I can help if you are really interested.

Comment: I do not want to implement something big, I just want to make dynamic queries based on the object I add. I have just 2 annotations and as values for them will be a PK and the name of the table. Again, is for learning purposes and I was thinking that this would be a great way to apply some knowledge :D